# After compile, which maven command can run the application?

Tags: maven-2, maven

Wanna run an application from maven command line, any command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

look into [Maven Exec Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" [-Dexec.args="argument1"] ...
```